# How do I retrieve the max value date from a group on SQL

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone suggest to me a SQL query, which I am fighting with?

I have two tables:

**Table_1**: `pos_tran` which has a schema like:

```
pos_tran
( 
entry_no CHAR 8 (NOT NULL PK),
barcode CHAR 8,
tran_amt NUMERIC 9,
tran_qty NUMERIC 9,
des CHAR 20
)
```

**Table_2**: `pos_tran_hd` and schema:

```
pos_tran_hd
(
entry_no CHAR 8 (NOT NULL PK), 
Location_id CHAR 3,
entry_date DATETIME8,
)
```

Now, I wanted to group the barcode after joining the two tables using `entry_no` and retrieve the `max(last date)` entry from the list as I am writing this, if someone emphasized me more

```
SELECT pthd.maxed, pt.barcode, tran_amt, tran_qty from pos_tran pt,
(
 SELECT entry_no, max(entry_date) maxed 
 FROM
 pos_tran_hd 
 where location_id=015 GROUP BY entry_no
)
pthd 
WHERE pthd.entry_no=pt.entry_no 
ORDER BY barcode,pthd.maxed
```

but this isn't working as I desired and giving me around 200,000 records without giving the max date, in this way:

```
2014-06-23 00:00:00.000 21155192 28000.000 7.00

2014-07-01 00:00:00.000 21155192 4000.000 1.00

2014-07-08 00:00:00.000 21155192 8000.000 2.00

2014-07-12 00:00:00.000 21155192 12000.000 3.00

2014-08-13 00:00:00.000 21155192 4000.000 1.00

2014-09-16 00:00:00.000 21155192 12000.000 3.00

2014-10-06 00:00:00.000 21155192 12000.000 3.00

2015-01-26 00:00:00.000 21155192 12000.000 3.00

2015-05-29 00:00:00.000 21155192 4000.000 1.00

2018-01-05 00:00:00.000 21155192 28000.000 4.00
```

but actually it should give me the last record which has `max(entry-date)` and the worst part of the database is that I am working on `Ms-SQL 2000`.

Please help me if anyone has a positive suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: what is your expected result ?

Comment: Your question says you're using "MySQL 2000", but the tag is for *SQL Server* - which is it now?? Please either fix the tag to reflect `mysql`, or change the question to include what you're really using!

Comment: It supposed to be 2018-01-05 only which is higher in above group.

Comment: Your question makes no sense, to group by `entry_no` in second table, you'd need to have multiple records with the same value in `entry_no` for `group by` to take ane effect. As you stated, it's primary key, so it is unique! Thus, grouping by it won't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query selects a max `entry_date` by `entry_no` while there is only one `entry_date` per `entry_no`. In your description, you were talking about "grouping by the barcode"... but when grouping by barcode (to show just one row per barcode), you can't display *amount* and *quantity* for each entry.

So, let's start with this one:

```
select pt.barcode, max(pthd.entry_date) maxed
from pos_tran pt
  inner join pos_tran_hd pthd on pt.entry_no = pthd.entry_no
group by pt.barcode
order by pt.barcode
```

Then, to display the complete row with the last `entry_date` per `barcode` and since you are still using SQL Server 2000, we need a subquery to calculate the `maxed` per `barcode` like I did before and compare these values to the ones we want to display:

```
SELECT pthd.entry_date maxed, pt.barcode, pt.tran_amt, pt.tran_qty 
FROM pos_tran pt
  INNER JOIN pos_tran_hd pthd ON pt.entry_no = pthd.entry_no
WHERE EXISTS (
    select pt2.barcode 
    from pos_tran pt2
      inner join pos_tran_hd pthd2 on pt2.entry_no = pthd2.entry_no
    group by pt2.barcode
    having pt2.barcode = pt.barcode AND max(pthd2.entry_date) = pthd.entry_date)
ORDER BY pt.barcode
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir... it works like charm much appreciated, i marked as a best answer for the day.

Answer (score 0):

you need `max()` function to get maximum date from pos_tran_hd  then join with it and get rest of the fields , later join it with pos_tran for getting corresponding max date result

pthd.maxed, pt.barcode, tran_amt, tran_qty

```
 select t.maxed,ps.barcode,ps.tran_amt,ps.tran_qty from 
 (SELECT pd.*
    from pos_tran_hd pd
     inner join
    (
     SELECT max(entry_date) maxed 
     FROM
     pos_tran_hd 
    )
    pthd 
     on pthd.maxed=pos_tran_hd.entry_date
    ) as t inner join pos_tran ps on t.entry_no =ps.entry_no
```